# What is a good (natural-language) naming scheme for belonging or property interfaces

Tags: c#, java, naming-conventions

*NOTE: This is **not** the popular interface naming question about
using or not using **"I"** at the beginning.*

I encounter often the problem to name
an interface, which indicates a belonging or property of a class.
*(Please see following list)*

Let's brainstorm, what kinds of interfaces are there?

- Indicate the **"kind"** of a class
  *DataStructure, Number, Thing*
- Indicate the **"profession"** of a class
  *Comparator, Executor, Listener*
- Indicate a **possible action** performed with a class
  *Comparable, Executable, Closeable*

The above are all clear to anyone, but let's get to my problem:

- Indicate a **belonging or property** of a class
  *HasListener, LinksToRoot, BelongsToParent, KnowsSibling, ContainsChildren,
  Named, WithDescription, ...?*

So, the last point is my problem. My english is not perfect,
but even I feel strange about such names.
They sound to me less successfully chosen then other, less meaningful.
But I often end up choosing right this kind of names.

It is even a greater discomfort in C# where interfaces are expected
to start with an **'I'**:
*IHasListener, IKnowsSibling, ...*
Sound to me like [LOLSPEAK](http://speaklolspeak.com/) *"I can haz a [kitteh](http://icanhascheezburger.com/), tawtally being full of
cuteness, OMG!@#!"*

**So, how should I name an interface which indicates a belonging or
property of a class?**

Comment: Isnt it more like type, behaviour and marker possibly?

Comment: Sorry, what's a "type, behaviour and marker possibility"?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is the way you choose to describe the "belonging of a property".

Most of your examples you gave can be mapped to the other categories you mentioned.

Just a few, for example:

*HasListener* => implements **Listenable**

*ContainsChildren* => implements **Parent**

*WithDescription* => implements **Descriptable**

Try to stick with more conventional naming schemes, preferably ones that describe your object in the best, more readable manner.

Also, make sure you are not *over-interfacing* your classes with useless interfaces. Make it very concise and to-the-point, otherwise you'll developers reading your code will get lost very fast.

Comment: I don't think that "HasListener => implements Listenable" is correct.

Comment: hasListener() should probably be a method for Listenable interface... Youy are mixing up lots of naming schemes...

Answer (score 4):

In some of the problem cases that you outline, I think there may be an answer by looking "from the other side":

```
HasListener -> Speaker
LinksToRoot, HasParent -> Child (or perhaps Node)
ContainsChildren -> Parent
```

Of course, different cases will be more or less obvious.

Comment: HasListener : a class contains a listener. Does this fact make it a speaker? But the other examples are good.

Comment: If not a speaker, perhaps a publisher.

Comment: Yes, good comments. Obviously Speaker was just a quick example to illustrate my thought. I guess that the problem domain of the application might give hints for better naming :o)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take some of what you're doing and turn them into "profession"-type interfaces:

- `HasListener` -> `ListenerContainer`
- `WithDescription` -> `DescriptionContainer` (`Describable` might also work, depending on what exactly a "description" is in this context)

A lot of your other interfaces seem to have something to do with a tree structure. I would suggest naming them according to their function in the tree.

- `ContainsChildren` -> `Parent` or `Collection`
- `BelongsToParent` -> `Child`

As for the other ones, I'd need to know more about what specifically these interfaces are for. Some of them, like `Named`, are probably named just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Those sounds like terrible interface names to me, I agree.  The "HasListener" sounds more like a method call that should return a boolean than an interface name.

Interfaces should not exist to hold/store properties of a class.  They should be used to outline a relationship that all classes that implement it should follow.  I personally stick with the "is a" relationship.  If there is a direct relationship, i.e. a cat "is a(n)" animal, then I will create an interface for it and name it Animal giving it a reasonable name.

I would be really interested in knowing what the "HasListener" interface outlines.  What exactly does it do?  Why can't it be named MyProjectListeners(replacing MyProject with the project name) that describes what listeners defined for this project must adhere to?

Comment: An object might do a lot more than have listeners. Having listeners might be just one of the few aspects that make up an object. E.g., a Window might support closing - but so might TabItems and other objects. So IClosable is a good interface that describes one aspect of a more complicated object.

Comment: Closable is indeed a good name for an interface.  I was more speaking of the other names such as "HasListener" which describes more of a state of an object than the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

*HasListener* is ok, as well as *Listenable*. I don't have anything against those.

But *IHasListener* is terrible: first because we don't really need the I prefix to tell that it is an interface (look at the class signature!) and second because it sounds like "I doesn't speak English".

The only interface in Java that I created with the I prefix was *IRule*. :)

Comment: But you should know, that in C# it is a naming convention, accepted by most developers, to start an interface with I.

Comment: Also in Java. Like it or not, many development standards use the convention of appending "I" to interface names.

Answer (score 0):

I actually quite like the "IHasListener" approach.

In the .NET Framework, you'll find this in interfaces such as:

- IRaiseListChangedEvents
- IHasXmlNode

Names like "Listenable" suggest that the implementation does the listening, not that it contains a listener. IHasListener clearly says what it does.

Comment: What's your opinion about the other names?